# Combining Multiple Forest Plots

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am trying to combine 4 forest plots into 1 matrix type plot output with 2 columns and 2 rows.

I have tried grid.arrange multiple times but I continue to get "only grobs allowed in list."

- The meta functions are done using **metacont** as my data is continuous

My code is as follows:

```
plot_ma<-forest(ma_meta, xlab = "title")

plot_m1<-forest(m1_meta, xlab = "title")

plot_m2<-forest(m2_meta, xlab = "title")

plot_ab<-forest(ab_meta, xlab = "title")
```

I would like for these to be combined in a matrix format so that my output can be one matrix of the 4 plots.

Answer (score 0):

The meta package and metafor package create plots that aren't compatible with grobs.  You could use the metaviz package to create your plots and then combine them with `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

The below code should work and was mostly taken from the [metaviz vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metaviz/vignettes/metaviz.html)

```
library(metaviz)

study_table <- data.frame(
    name = exrehab[, "study_name"],
    eventsT = paste(exrehab$ai, "/", exrehab$ai + exrehab$bi, sep = ""),
    eventsC = paste(exrehab$ci, "/", exrehab$ci + exrehab$di, sep = ""))

summary_table <- data.frame(
    name = "Summary",
    eventsT = paste(sum(exrehab$ai), "/", sum(exrehab$ai + exrehab$bi), sep = ""),
    eventsC = paste(sum(exrehab$ci), "/", sum(exrehab$ci + exrehab$di), sep = ""))

g1 <- viz_forest(x = exrehab[, c("logrr", "logrr_se")], variant = "classic",
            col = "Greys", xlab = "logRR", annotate_CI = T, 
            study_table = study_table,
            summary_table = summary_table,
            table_headers = c("ID", "Events (T)", "Events (C)"))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1,g1)
```